# задача "Симпатичный узор" на python

Tags: python, матрицы

Прописываю логику в цикле if а пайчарм пишет ошибку что я в if от строчки отнимаю число, хотя там работа с индексами должна быть(в задаче буквы но я и цифры вводил 0,1): TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

```
a = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    b = []
    for j in range(n):
        b.append(input())
    a.append(b)
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if a[i][j] == a[i - 1][j] and [i][j] == a[i + 1][j] and a[i][j] == a[i][j + 1] and a[i][j] == a[i][j - 1]: 
            print('no')
        else:
            print('yes')
```

Comment: https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=topic&id_course=1&id_section=8&id_topic=121 условие задачки

Comment: Не от строчки, а от списка. А вот в списке исключительно строчки, потому что b состоит из одних строк.

Comment: Ну и если посмотреть на логику, то что именно сравнивается в цикле? Как список может быть индексом?

Comment: Такое впечатление что этот способ реализации запрост для этой задачи, мысль была обращаться как к системе координат но требование прописывать к 4 значениям, и тут будет ошибка, а прописать на базе индексов слишком много кода прийдется писать и это не эффективно(

Comment: Нашел такое решение этой задачи но до конца как оно работает еще не разобрался: a = [input() for _ in range(4)] if all([len(set(a[i][j:j + 2] + a[i + 1][j:j + 2])) == 2 for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]): print('YES') else: print('NO') Если знаете, прокоментируйте его плиз?

Answer (score 0):

Во втором цикле переменная i является списком, следовательно обращение `a[i]` эквивалентно `a[[1,2,3]]` что вызовет ошибку. Здесь следует исспользовать функцию index `ii=a.index(i)` Вот изменённый код

```
a = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    b = []
    for j in range(n):
        b.append(input())
    a.append(b)
for i in a:
    ii=a.index(i) #получаем индекс элемента i
    for j in i:
        if a[ii][j] == a[ii - 1][j] and [ii][j] == a[ii + 1][j] and a[ii][j] == a[ii][j + 1] and a[ii][j] == a[ii][j - 1]: 
            print('no')
        else:
            print('yes')
```

[upd] проблемма не решена? внимание на строку `b.append(input())`

Comment: При таком варианте кода ошибка TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Такое впечатление что этот способ реализации запрост для этой задачи, мысль была обращаться как к системе координат но требование прописывать к 4 значениям, и тут будет ошибка, а прописать на базе индексов слишком много кода прийдется писать и это не эффективно(

Comment: Нашел такое решение этой задачи но до конца как оно работает еще не разобрался: a = [input() for _ in range(4)]
if all([len(set(a[i][j:j + 2] + a[i + 1][j:j + 2])) == 2 for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')